# Font size based on dpi, android

Tags: android

This seems to be a basic question, but I am not able to figure it out.
I am creating an app which will run on ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. I have a phone which is hdpi.
Now font sizes are best judged when seen on a physical phone/tablet.

So say If it looks good on 18 pixel font on hdpi, on what sizes would it look good on others.
Any ideas, best known good practices?

Thanks

Comment: Text size(sp) will increase/decrease according to screen size and resolution. OS will take care of it.

Comment: Yes. Using Sp should be & is a recommended way to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. Try using `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);` in Java code

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sp` as the unit of the fontsize. an 18px font should be 9sp on an hdpi device, and the os automatically scales it based on the density.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
```